# POST action - no parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-post

I have a problem. I want to do a post action and I'm doing it like this:

```
string post_data = string.Format("taskId={0}&inputId={1}&value={2}", taskId, inputId, "101");

string uri = "http://localhost:60837/Default.aspx";
// Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
        // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
        request.Method = "POST";
        // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array
        var byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(post_data);
        // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        // Get the request stream.
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        // Write the data to the request stream.
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        // Close the Stream object.
        dataStream.Close();
        // Get the response.
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        // Display the status.
        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        // Read the content.
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
        // Display the content.
        Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
        // Clean up the streams.
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
```

This is my code-behing of my default.aspx:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write(Caller.Process(Request.RawUrl, Request.QueryString, Request.UserHostAddress));
    }
}
```

And my Process method look like this:
    static readonly string
            //paramDefinition = "definition",
            paramTaskId = "taskId",
            paramInputId = "inputId",
            paramValue = "value";

```
    static public string Process(string query, NameValueCollection collection, string ip)
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        Func<string, bool> check = str =>
        {
            if (!collection.AllKeys.Contains(str))
            {
                result.AppendLine(string.Format("No {0} parameter. ", str));
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        };
        if (check(paramTaskId) && check(paramInputId) && check(paramValue))
        {
            result.Append("OK");
            Execute(query, collection, ip);
        }
        else
        {
            WriteLog(result.ToString(), query, ip);
        }

        return result.ToString();
    }
```

The problem is I get no parameters on my Deafault.aspx. When I'm doing it in my browser everything is ok. Do you know what can be a problem? Thanks in advance;)

Comment: When you test in your browser, do you pass them via `GET` or `POST`?  Does your code in `Default.aspx` look for the variables in `GET`, `POST`, or both?

Comment: In browser i just enter text like this: http://localhost:60837/default.aspx?taskId=3&value=10&inputId=44

Comment: Using the browser method, you are passing the variables by `GET`.  Using the code, you are passing by `POST`.  They are referenced differently when looking them up `Request.QueryString[..] vs Request.Form[..]` (unless you are using the catch-all method which is discouraged).  How are you retrieving the variables inside `Default.aspx`?  That could make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the browser method, you are passing the variables by `GET` (i.e., using parameters passed as part of the url). Using the code, you are passing by `POST`.  Those are two different things, and they are handled differently when processing on the server side.

When you reference the variables in the code for Default.aspx, you are using `Request.QueryString` which looks specifically for parameters passed via `GET`, or in the url.  To retrieve the variables passed via `POST`, you need to use `Request.Form["varName"]`.

Comment: Yes, except replace `Request.QueryString` with `Request.Form`.

Comment: Thank you very much:) After 6 hours sometimes it's hard to think:)